# Visualize data in Pycharm in the same way as in Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, ide, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to visualize data in pycharm in the same way that you can do in `jupyter`?

For instance in `jupyter` you can run a single line at a time and see the output which can be helpful for working with data sets.

Of course you can just use a function like `head()` or `show()` to see what is going on but you have to run the whole file (as opposed to one line at a time in jupyter) and it can make working with data a bit harder to understand.

[image: Jupyter Display]

Does anyone have any recommendations for me in terms of pycharm as that is what I am most familar with, or do you think it is worth me learning something like `jupyter`?

Comment: Hi @user9940344 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @DinkoPehar Hi. the answer to this was to just learn jupyter which I have started to do. Thank you.

Comment: If none if these answers helped you, consider adding your own answer to this question and marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Atom and install the package Hydrogen? it offers you the same possibilities as Jupyter while working in a script (not a notebook). 
You can execute the code line by line like in Jupyter by clicking ctrl+Enter or run it as a script. Here's the [documentation of the package](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen).

Atom is a light IDE so it combines both the power of Jupyter and PyCharm. I have used it and it is great and has so many packages like hydrogen, pep8 (helps to write a code that is conform to the pep8) and code beautifiers (for Python, R, JSON,etc), and a lot of great features.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning Jupyter. Although PyCharm is an excellent IDE, running Jupyter in it looks clunky and something like this:

[image: PyCharm Jupyter]